# Convert Javascript Object to array of arrays with two values

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts

Currently, my script produces an object with a format as follows:

```
{name: numerical value, name: numerical value}
```

Highcharts, the charting library I am using requires data to be in an array of arrays with two values, example:

```
[ ["name", "numerical value"], ["name", "numerical value"], ["name", "numerical value"] ]
```

How can I convert my javascript object into arrays within an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop through the object's keys, creating a new pair for each:

```
var obj = { name: 3, name2: 4 /* etc. */ };
var data = [];

for ( f in obj )
{
  var pair = [ f, obj[f] ];
  data.push(pair);
}
```

Or, a less-verbose version of that loop:

```
for ( f in obj )
{
  data.push( [ f, obj[f] ] );
}
```

```js
var obj = { name: 3, name2: 4, name3: 72 };
var data = [];

for ( f in obj )
{
  data.push( [ f, obj[f] ] );
}

console.log( JSON.stringify(data) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var data = {name: 'numerical value', name1: 'numerical value'};

var res = Object.keys(data).map(function (el) {
  return [el, data[el]];
});

console.log(res);
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/jetehe/1/edit?js,output)

Comment: Keep in mind that if you're supporting IE8 or earlier (among other older browsers), you'll need to bring your own implementation of `keys()` and `map()`. Examples are provided at the linked pages.

Comment: Thanks! Very nice and compact answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you read this in 2018 you can use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) method

```
function convertObjectToList(obj) {
  return Object.entries(obj);
}
```